# Removal of colons in directory name

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

Currently the directory getting automatically created for a program I am working with includes colons (`:`), creating issues when I try manipulate the directory. Could anyone help me first remove this colon, and then be able to `cd` into the renamed directory? (So I guess I would have to equal the new directory name to a variable?)

Example:

- current directory name: `Lang-32b-Branch:Line`
- desired directory name: `Lang-32b-BranchLine`

Comment: “[The colon is] creating issues when I try manipulate the directory” — What issues do you mean? The colon is mostly any other character (on Ubuntu), it shouldn’t create any issues.

Comment: I have another piece of software that needs to navigate the directory and the colon does not play nice at all (as a jar file is created according to the name of the directory).

Comment: To make things easier on you, you could also use tab completion once you have typed part of the directory name, which will automatically escape the colon for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To achieve this manually, an in a simple manner you could use the `mv` command with some strong quoting to ensure that the shell doesn't interpret the colon as a special character:

```
mv 'Lang-32b-Branch:Line' 'Lang-32b-BranchLine' && cd 'Lang-32b-BranchLine'
```

An alternate approach is to use a variable and the one of the features of Bash parameter expansion, which may be more useful if you wish to automate this directory name change into a script:

```
dir=Lang-32b-Branch:Line
mv "$dir" "${dir//:/}"
```

The expansion of `"${dir//:/}"` will replace any occurrence of the colon character with nothing, giving the expected result of Lang-32b-BranchLine. Using `"${dir/:/}"` would result in only the first occurrence of the colon being removed, though that would still work for your given example.

As a one-liner to move and cd into the directory:

```
dir=Lang-32b-Branch:Line ; mv "$dir" "${dir//:/}" && cd "${dir//:/}"
```

Or if you wished to capture the modified directory name into a variable named new_dir:

```
dir=Lang-32b-Branch:Line ; new_dir="${dir//:/}"; mv "$dir" "$new_dir" && cd "$new_dir"
```

A great guide to Bash parameter expansion is available [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the link too, its certainly helping me wrap my head around this

Comment: `$_` always holds the last argument of the last command you called (see my answer below) – that can save a lot of typing! The keyboard shortcut to enter it on the fly is `Alt+.`. `${dir//:/}` can be further shortened to `${dir//:}`.

Comment: I thought I could do away with the last / in the expansion, but wasn't 100% sure @dessert . I often use `Alt+.` on cli but never realy use `$_`. Thanks for the extra tips!

Comment: What shell interprets `:` as a special character (outside of history expansion and as an operator, which is irrelevant here)?

Comment: I don't know of one @KonradRudolph, though that was the issue the OP had described, so I answered with regards to that. I admit I'd not had any issues with using the initial commands without quoting.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Possibly could be a problem having a : in a directory name because of *`$PATH`*... (I'm not saying in the case of the OP it's relevant so much as saying it's a possibility - one that crossed my mind immediately but not one I gave much thought to either.)

Answer (score 8):

If you want a general command to rename several files and/or directories with one or more colons, you can use `rename`,

```
rename 's/://g' *
```

After that you can `cd` into any of the directories (that you modified) as usual (without any quotes).

---

Alternate command line according to the tips in comments by @DavidFoerster and @dessert,

```
rename 's/://g' *\:*/
```

- If you want to limit the rename actions to directories, you should add a slash after the wild-card star.
- You can also put a colon in the wild-card expression to limit the selection of files to those, that contain a colon in the file name, which might make the action faster, if a huge amount of directories are to be searched,

Edit:

@EliahKagan suggests to start with a 'dry run' with the option -n,

```
rename -n 's/://g' *
```

> which just prints out what renaming operations would be performed.
>   Then it can be run again with the -n option removed to actually rename
>   the files. This helps avoid mistakes such as accidentally renaming a
>   bunch of files one actually wanted to leave alone.

Comment: When using `rename`, I recommend running it with `-n` first (for example: `rename -n 's/://g' *`), which just prints out what renaming operations would be performed. Then it can be run again with the `-n` option removed to actually rename the files. This helps avoid mistakes such as accidentally renaming a bunch of files one actually wanted to leave alone.

Answer (score 4):

If it's only the one directory you can use `mv` and `cd`. To make use of the power of [`bash` History Expansion](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc29) and the special parameter `$_`:

```
mv Lang-32b-Branch:Line !#:$:s/:/ && cd $_
```

`!#:$:s/:/` is replaced with the last word (`$`) of the current command line (`!#`), where the first `:` is `s`ubstituted by nothing. If you want *every* colon to be removed, change it to `!#:$:gs/:/` (`g`lobally). `$_` is simply replaced with the last command's last argument.